# how to remove margin in pdf report using ireport

Tags: jasper-reports, export-to-pdf

I design report using ireport and when I export the report in pdf I find some margin (green space) in top and bottom and also the report is centered in pdf. when I print, there is blanck space at the place of the green space in pdf.

How to avoid margin (green space) and avoid centered report in pdf.

Please see image for more information.

[image: Remove green space and avoid center]

[image: Printing preview]

Please find this gist contains JRXML file content

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/ea94f0b6929d69b608c3daea19fff46f

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I have updated my question with gist link contain jrxml content. @AlexK

Comment: You should post *small, minimal* template (not huge one) to reproduce the problem

Comment: *Small* - in size, *minimal* - it should contains the only code for reproducing issue (nothing extra). For example: not styles or 10+ fields, 30+ parameters are needed to reproduce your issue

Comment: I still do not understand what you mean by _small, minimal_ template but I added page format and report properties in case it is what you want to help me solve the problem. I have also reduce gist @AlexK